# How hide select date in bootstrap-dateTimePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have this DateTimePicker:

[image]

I need edit only the time , so I need only show this :

[image]

code:

```
setDateTime: function(index){
    $('#date_time_'+index+'_id').datetimepicker({
        showClose:true,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
        ignoreReadonly: true
    });
},
```

So the input showing the date and time is fine, but I need edit only the time

Im using this :
[bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disableddates)

but I don't know what option use.
Sorry my english.

Comment: Which datetimepicker "library" are you using? jquery-ui?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap-datetimepicker sorry

Comment: See my answer, I solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I think that without updating of bootstrap datetimepicker lib you would have to use alternative. As this library is not prepared for just time picker.

Please use something like this instead. Same format, but more options for you:
http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Then you can set what you want just with this

```
$('#date_time_'+index+'_id').datetimepicker({
  pickDate: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify only time in the [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/9jkxL4su/

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'LT'
});
```

**EDIT:**

To show calendar (toggle) icon, you'll need to fire a toggle-click when the picker is shown:

https://jsfiddle.net/pv8Lhy9t/

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    allowInputToggle: true,
    showClose: true
});

$('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.show", function(){
     var toggle = $(this).find('a[data-action="togglePicker"]');
     if(toggle.length > 0) toggle.click();

     // To hide the toggle back to calendar button, uncomment line below
     // $(this).find('a[data-action="togglePicker"]').hide();
});
```

NOTE:
You can remove the ability for the user to toggle back to edit the date. Just uncomment the last line as shown in the code above.

READONLY: To restrict ability to edit date manually, just give the input field a readonly attribute and also set the `ignoreReadonly` property to true in the picker: https://jsfiddle.net/xgm99t5o/

Comment: Hi , thank you but I need show the date too in the input , but only edit the time

Comment: Also added a jsFiddle that shows how you can "lock down" the date so that only time can be modified. And the form will still get the full datepicker value.

Comment: The "readonly" jsFiddle link at the bottom is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

What is the name of the component ?

Perhaps you can use something like: 
pickDate: false;
or only
format: 'HH:mm',

In this component it looks like: https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/